# How to check AWS SQS Connection idle time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Here is the thing,
I'm creating an SQS Connection. I'm using the same connection to create consumers to listen to two different queues(Q1, Q2).

Enabling and disabling to queue is handled by the Admin user of application through a UI.

So, Whenever I disable Q1 consumer, I shouldn't close the connection, and close the connection only when both Q1 & Q2 Consumers are disabled, I can't afford to write complex code to check if both consumers are disabled.

1. Is there a way to check idle time of an open SQSConnection.

or

2. I would like to know the cost of keeping an SQSConnection open all the time

or

3. How about opening two different connections

here is how I'm creating the connection

```
SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(
            new ProviderConfiguration(), ((AmazonSQSClientBuilder)
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(sqsRegion)).
                withCredentials(
                    _getCredentialsProvider(awsSecretKey, awsAccessKey)));
_connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire question, here, seems premised on the unfortunate name `SQSConnectionFactory`, which isn't what this really is.  A more accurate name might have been something like `SQSConfiguredClientFactory`.

> None of the `createConnection` methods set-up the physical connection to SQS
>
> https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/SQSConnectionFactory.java

...because SQS doesn't actually use established/continuous "connections."

The service API interactions take place over HTTPS, with transient connections being created, kept alive, and destroyed as other methods (e.g. `receiveMessage(queueUrl)`) need them.

So with regard to your questions: 1. connections are not left "open" in any meaningful/relevant sense, so there is nothing to check; 2. the only cost comes from actually *using* the connections to send/receive/delete messages; and 3. this seems unnecessary for the reasons indicated above.